# is async "all" there is to C# 5.0?

Tags: c#, c#-5.0

Yes, I know `async` and friends does **a lot** behind the scenes, but how about "clean up" items (WPF support?) from the various wish lists?  Or are there other C# 5.0 features that will be coming?

Comment: what? another c#? i hope it has readonly properties :)

Comment: I have a feeling there aren't a lot of people on StackOverflow that could tell you right now if there are features that have yet to be announced.

Comment: then this will be too localized question to this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's all that's been announced so far.

In his PDC talk, Anders did suggest that there *may* be some other features as well. My guess is that there won't be anything on the same scale, but I'd certainly *like* there to be some extras. (I'd point to a specific bit of the video, but unfortunately it looks like it's not available any more. Odd.)

It's worth bearing in mind that [Eric Lippert's blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20151204230821/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/28/asynchrony-in-c-5-part-one.aspx) makes this point (in purple, of course, which sadly I don't think I can emulate here):

> We are absolutely positively not announcing any **dates** or **ship vehicles** at this time, so don't even ask. Even if I knew, which I don't, and even if my knowledge had the faintest chance of being accurate, which it doesn't, I still wouldn't tell you.

I don't think it's going to be worth trying to pry many extra details out of anyone for the moment. I suggest we all have a lot of fun with async (and in particular give feedback - I'm sure that the earlier MS hears community feedback, the more likely it will be to affect the shipping product) and just wait to hear more.

Comment: In particular, Anders Hejlsberg was asked in his talk whether other (non-async-related) features were coming and he said he wouldn't comment on specifics yet, but there would be.

Comment: @Joey: Yes, but I don't think it would be fair to hold Anders to that fairly vague promise :) Suppose MS decided they wanted to get the async stuff out in production ASAP - possibly to help Windows Phone 7 get more decent applications into the marketplace quickly. If they decided to put the other stuff off until C# 6, I don't think that would be unreasonable.

Comment: So what is the impact to F#? Is F# going to lose its unique advantage?

Comment: @Liang Wu: I don't think async is all that F# has going for it - and there are suggestions that F#'s async support is neater in some ways. I think F# will be just fine :)

Comment: Wait, what? My dreams of extension properties are getting crushed! :)

Comment: interestingly on the mono roadmap, they suggest C# 5 support in the next version which they expect in Fall 2011 http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_Project_Roadmap

Comment: @Mark: Yes, interesting, isn't it? I doubt that the async stuff will change much now - it'll be interesting to see what else, if anything, comes in C# 5. (Eric Lippert has said that foreach semantics of capturing variables may change, but that's pretty minor.)

Comment: Didn't they promise us meta-programing? [C#5 and Meta-Programming](http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2010/05/31/c-5-and-meta-programming/) I don't see any metaprogramming CTP! :-(

Comment: @xanatos: I don't believe I've heard anything about the Compiler as a Service API coming with C# 5. I believe that's slated for later. I believe Microsoft only said Compiler as a Service was coming "later than C# 4".